# Дамп памяти И MemberwiseClone()?

Tags: c#

Объясните *Человеческим языком* что такое Дамп памяти? И каким образом он используется при вызове MembeerwiseClone() ?
Всем привет, просто я прохожу онлайн курс, в одном из уроков которого автор говорит, что при использовании MembeerwiseClone() в отличии от использовании конструктора - цитирую "по сути "забегает" в область памяти, хватает ее дамп и простым копированием - копирует его в другую область,перезаписывает адреса и никаких конструкторов MembeerwiseClone() не вызывает" . А и еще один вопрос: о перезаписи каких адресов в скопированном дампе памяти говорит автор ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ГуголТранслейт нам подсказывает: `dump` - `a copying of stored data to a different location, performed typically as a protection against loss.` что можно перевести как: "копирование ранее сохраненных данных в другое место (расположение) осуществляемое чаще всего с целью защиты данных от их потери."
В случае клонирования объекта с помощью `MemberwiseClone()` `value` данные копируются с помощью считывания значений и записывания их по новому адресу в памяти, а в случае `reference` данные не копируются, а копируются только ссылки на эти данные.

Не уверен, что получилось объяснить яснее:)

Допустим, у вас в классе есть два свойства:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public int[] Cells { get; set; }
```

так вот значение Id будет скопировано в клоне, т.е. оно будет "свое", а вот в случае Cells клон будет содержать ссылку на Cells оригинала.

После появления вашего комментария решил вам дать полный пример, тем более вы после этого вопроса еще один вопрос решили задать.

*Метод `MemberwiseClone()` применяется к объектам, а не к отдельным свойствам.*

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int[] Cells { get; set; }

    //поверхностное копирование самого себя
    public MyClass GetShallowClone()
    {
        return (MyClass)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    //глубокое копирования самого себя
    public MyClass GetDeepClone()
    {
        MyClass clone = (MyClass)this.MemberwiseClone();

        //копируем отдельно массив, т.к. он является ссылочным типом
        clone.Cells = new int[this.Cells.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Cells.Length; i++)
        {
            clone.Cells[i] = this.Cells[i];
        }

        return clone;
   }
  public override string ToString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 10));
        Console.WriteLine($"Имя:{Name}, Номер:{Id}");
        foreach (var item in this.Cells)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 10));

        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Обращаю ваше внимание на то, что ссылочные типы к коим относится массив при поверхностном клонировании просто копируют ссылку см. применение ниже

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass original = new MyClass() { Name="original", Id = 1 };
        original.Cells = new[] { 5, 7, 9 };
        //выводим оригинал
        original.ToString();


        //Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 10));

        MyClass shallowClone = original.GetShallowClone();
        Console.WriteLine("Поверхностный клон сразу после создания");
        shallowClone.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Изменяем клон");
        shallowClone.Name = "shallow";
        shallowClone.Id = 2;
        shallowClone.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Оригинал");
        original.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Изменяем у клона значение массива");
        shallowClone.Cells[0] = 1000;

        Console.WriteLine("Клон");
        shallowClone.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Оригинал, у него тоже изменился массив, т.к. массив - ссылочный тип");
        original.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(new String('+', 10));

        Console.WriteLine("Глубокий клон сразу после создания");
        MyClass deepClone = original.GetDeepClone();
        deepClone.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Изменяем глубокий клон");
        deepClone.Name = "deepClone";
        deepClone.Id = 3;
        deepClone.Cells[0] = 11111;
        deepClone.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Оригинал, у него не изменился массив");
        original.ToString();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: т.е  public int Id { get; set; } - Вы клонируете с помощью MembeerwiseClone() ,а public int[] Cells { get; set; } создается клон с помощью reference ?

Comment: @BadCats я добавил пример для ясности.